# Dart can't find index of object in list with indexOf()

Tags: list, dart, indexof

So, either I have a very weird problem here on my hand, or I'm just plain dumb.

I have a list of Objects. The Attributes of each object are a few doubles, an int and a String.

My problem is that `list.indexOf(object)` returns -1 (e.g. indexOf() could not find the element) even if there is an object in the list whose attributes are carbon copy of the object whose index I want to find.

Even `list.indexOf(list[0])` returns -1, for some goddamn reason (Edit: Initially mistyped the -1 as 0). And yes, the list actually has data in it.

Here's the code of my object:

```dart
class Standard {
  double l;
  double a;
  double b;
  double lUpperTolerance;
  double lLowerTolerance;
  double aUpperTolerance;
  double aLowerTolerance;
  double bUpperTolerance;
  double bLowerTolerance;
  double eTolerance;
  int timestamp;
  String identStr;

  Standard(
      {this.l,
      this.a,
      this.b,
      this.lUpperTolerance,
      this.lLowerTolerance,
      this.aUpperTolerance,
      this.aLowerTolerance,
      this.bUpperTolerance,
      this.bLowerTolerance,
      this.eTolerance,
      this.timestamp,
      this.identStr});

  factory Standard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    if (jsonData != null) {
      double l = (jsonData['l'] ?? 0.0) as double;
      double a = (jsonData['a'] ?? 0.0) as double;
      double b = (jsonData['b'] ?? 0.0) as double;
      double lUpperTolerance = (jsonData['lUpperTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double lLowerTolerance = (jsonData['lLowerTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double aUpperTolerance = (jsonData['aUpperTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double aLowerTolerance = (jsonData['aLowerTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double bUpperTolerance = (jsonData['bUpperTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double bLowerTolerance = (jsonData['bLowerTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double eTolerance = (jsonData['eTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      int timestamp = (jsonData['timestamp'] ?? 1500000000) as int;
      String identStr = (jsonData['identStr'] ?? '0') as String;
      return Standard(
          l: l,
          a: a,
          b: b,
          lUpperTolerance: lUpperTolerance,
          lLowerTolerance: lLowerTolerance,
          aUpperTolerance: aUpperTolerance,
          aLowerTolerance: aLowerTolerance,
          bUpperTolerance: bUpperTolerance,
          bLowerTolerance: bLowerTolerance,
          eTolerance: eTolerance,
          timestamp: timestamp,
          identStr: identStr);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'l': l,
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'lUpperTolerance': lUpperTolerance,
        'lLowerTolerance': lLowerTolerance,
        'aUpperTolerance': aUpperTolerance,
        'aLowerTolerance': aLowerTolerance,
        'bUpperTolerance': bUpperTolerance,
        'bLowerTolerance': bLowerTolerance,
        'eTolerance': eTolerance,
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'identStr': identStr,
      };

  void dump() {
    print('l: ' + this.l.toString());
    print('a: ' + this.a.toString());
    print('b: ' + this.b.toString());
    print('lUpper: ' + this.lUpperTolerance.toString());
    print('lLower: ' + this.lLowerTolerance.toString());
    print('aUpper: ' + this.aUpperTolerance.toString());
    print('aLower: ' + this.aLowerTolerance.toString());
    print('bUpper: ' + this.bUpperTolerance.toString());
    print('bLower: ' + this.bLowerTolerance.toString());
    print('eTolerance: ' + this.eTolerance.toString());
    print('timestamp: ' + this.timestamp.toString());
    print('identStr: ' + this.identStr.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your Object? Are you sure you are not overriding the == operator in your object?

Comment: @smotastic added it to the end of the question. I can't find any mention of indexOf in any of my code apart from where I want to use it to find the index of an object, and Ctrl + Q on the indexOf shows the help from `list.dart`

Comment: `indexOf` depends on object equality.  If you didn't provide an `operator ==` for your object, then the default notion of equality is simply object identity. `list.indexOf(list[0])` shouldn't return -1 if that is what you literally typed, however. Please provide reproduction code that demonstrates the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Because I wasn't quite sure if I realy stumbled on what could be considered a bug here, I actually put that exact line in my code and ran it. 

But yes, it was a missing equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it turns out that I would have needed to add a method to compare objects, so my class looks like this in the end:

```dart
class Standard {
  double l;
  double a;
  double b;
  double lUpperTolerance;
  double lLowerTolerance;
  double aUpperTolerance;
  double aLowerTolerance;
  double bUpperTolerance;
  double bLowerTolerance;
  double eTolerance;
  int timestamp;
  String identStr;

  Standard({this.l,
    this.a,
    this.b,
    this.lUpperTolerance,
    this.lLowerTolerance,
    this.aUpperTolerance,
    this.aLowerTolerance,
    this.bUpperTolerance,
    this.bLowerTolerance,
    this.eTolerance,
    this.timestamp,
    this.identStr});

  @override
  bool operator ==(o) {
    if (o is! Standard) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return o.l == l &&
          o.a == a &&
          o.b == b &&
          o.lUpperTolerance == lUpperTolerance &&
          o.lLowerTolerance == lLowerTolerance &&
          o.aUpperTolerance == aUpperTolerance &&
          o.aLowerTolerance == aLowerTolerance &&
          o.bUpperTolerance == bUpperTolerance &&
          o.bLowerTolerance == bLowerTolerance &&
          o.eTolerance == eTolerance &&
          o.timestamp == timestamp &&
          o.identStr == identStr;
    }
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => super.hashCode;

  factory Standard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    if (jsonData != null) {
      double l = (jsonData['l'] ?? 0.0) as double;
      double a = (jsonData['a'] ?? 0.0) as double;
      double b = (jsonData['b'] ?? 0.0) as double;
      double lUpperTolerance = (jsonData['lUpperTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double lLowerTolerance = (jsonData['lLowerTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double aUpperTolerance = (jsonData['aUpperTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double aLowerTolerance = (jsonData['aLowerTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double bUpperTolerance = (jsonData['bUpperTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double bLowerTolerance = (jsonData['bLowerTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      double eTolerance = (jsonData['eTolerance'] ?? 1.0) as double;
      int timestamp = (jsonData['timestamp'] ?? 1500000000) as int;
      String identStr = (jsonData['identStr'] ?? '0') as String;
      return Standard(
          l: l,
          a: a,
          b: b,
          lUpperTolerance: lUpperTolerance,
          lLowerTolerance: lLowerTolerance,
          aUpperTolerance: aUpperTolerance,
          aLowerTolerance: aLowerTolerance,
          bUpperTolerance: bUpperTolerance,
          bLowerTolerance: bLowerTolerance,
          eTolerance: eTolerance,
          timestamp: timestamp,
          identStr: identStr);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'l': l,
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'lUpperTolerance': lUpperTolerance,
        'lLowerTolerance': lLowerTolerance,
        'aUpperTolerance': aUpperTolerance,
        'aLowerTolerance': aLowerTolerance,
        'bUpperTolerance': bUpperTolerance,
        'bLowerTolerance': bLowerTolerance,
        'eTolerance': eTolerance,
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'identStr': identStr,
      };

  void dump() {
    print('l: ' + this.l.toString());
    print('a: ' + this.a.toString());
    print('b: ' + this.b.toString());
    print('lUpper: ' + this.lUpperTolerance.toString());
    print('lLower: ' + this.lLowerTolerance.toString());
    print('aUpper: ' + this.aUpperTolerance.toString());
    print('aLower: ' + this.aLowerTolerance.toString());
    print('bUpper: ' + this.bUpperTolerance.toString());
    print('bLower: ' + this.bLowerTolerance.toString());
    print('eTolerance: ' + this.eTolerance.toString());
    print('timestamp: ' + this.timestamp.toString());
    print('identStr: ' + this.identStr.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: The `hashCode` here just uses `Object.hashCode` and is not compatible with the declared `==`, so it's possible to put an object into a `HashSet`, and not find it there if looking up with an equal-but-not-identical value.

Comment: Does this explain why this also didn't work? `list.indexOf(list[0])` The default should be to look for same references. And this should find the same reference in the list as you are searching for the first object in the list?

Comment: I dunno why that didn't work,  but this solved my problem.